# How to use backslash in user on ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh, terminal, ssh-config

So my university supplied access to a server with backslashes, like this:

```
ssh portoalegre\\15280433@university.server.br
```

and I decided to copy my public key there to be more secure (and not having to type the password every time). This works fine! However ... I then decided to set an entry in `~/.ssh/config` so I could just login using

```
ssh university
```

But it didn't worked. It keeps asking me for my password. Here is the entry I setup on the config file:

```
Host university
  Hostname university.server.br
  User portoalegre\\15280433
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I escape/handle those 2 backslashes in the config file? I'm using a Ubuntu Desktop machine to connect to the server via its default terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\\` in your SSH command really represent a single `\` (try `echo portoalegre\\15280433@university.server.br` and see what that displays). So the first thing to try is to use a single backslash in your SSH config:

```
Host university
  Hostname university.server.br
  User portoalegre\15280433
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. The instructions supplied said in unix/linux we needed to use 2 backslashes, and 1 in windows/putty. Did not tried with a single backslash. Thanks man!

Comment: 2 backslahes in the command line, one backslash escaping the second, because bash uses backslashes for special purposes. But your id only has one and that's what the SSH config needs.